# Image border in Strict HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css, border, image, w3c-validation

I have the following to display an clickable image (with no border) on a website:

```
<a href="link"><img src="img" border="0" /></a>
```

However this is not strict XHTML 1.0 so I changed it too:

```
<img src="img" class="mystyle" />
```

And the CSS:

```
mystyle img
{
    border: 0px;
}
```

However this only works in Safari & Chrome and does not work in IE & FireFox.

I understand that the w3 validators aren't necessary but was wondering if anyone has come across this and possibly a fix :)

EDIT: Style was a typo, I meant class ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Needs some changes (*<strike>i am surprised to hear that it works in **any** browser</strike>, well looks like webkit-based browsers do not put a border around image links, as @Adriano mentioned in his comment*)

in **Html**

```
<img src="img" class="mystyle" />
```

because the `style` attribute is to assign property values directely, and not to reference a css rules. The `class` attribute is used for that.

and in **CSS**

```
.mystyle
{
    border: 0px;
}
```

because to signify a class rule you put a `.` to it (*`#` for ids*). And we removed the `img` from there because it would mean that you want to style `img` tags that are contained in some other element that has the `mystyle` class.

Comment: Thanks. I am now surprised that it worked in Safari/Chrome. As I mentioned above I meant class, not style in my HTML snippet. Maybe it's was clever enough to work it out? ^^

Comment: perhaps chrome and safari (both based on webkit, aren't they) display linked images without borders by default, so you got the behaviour you wanted anyway

Answer (score 2):

Your css is missing the "." in front of mystyle.  This is the css you want:

.mystyle img
{
    border: 0px;
}

In your html, use the "class" tag, not the "style" tag.  You would use style when you include in line Css, such as:

```
<img href="img" style="border: none;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it should be `class="mystyle"` not `style="mystyle"`.

Secondly, since the `<img`> tag is the same element that has the `mystyle` class, your CSS is wrong.

The CSS you've defined is for an element called `mystyle` which is inside of another element called `img`.

How you actually want to define the style is `img.mystyle`.

So your CSS code would look like this:

```
img.mystyle {
    border:0px;
}
```

and your HTML would look like this:

```
<img src="img" class="mystyle" />
```

To be honest though, I'd prefer to have this apply to *all* images, so I wouldn't bother with the `mystyle` bit at all; just have a stylesheet entry for `img` on its own to remove any borders. If you need to add one to a specific image later, you can always override it, but I'd rather have it off by default.

As for the mystery as to how the original code worked in Chrome/Safari but not Firefox/IE: I suspect that Chrome/Safari have dropped the default border. So it's not so much that they worked for you, it's more that those browsers don't even need you to do this, whereas Firefox and IE are still using the old default style for image links that defaults to giving them a border so they do need the override.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be `<img src="img" class="mystyle" />`?

Answer (score 0):

my quess is that you don't catch the css propertly.
it should be `**.**mystyle img`

```
<a href="link" ><img style="border: 0px" src="http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo16.png"  /></a>
```