# HTML4 strict: border="0" is deprecated, how to replace it

Tags: html, css

Checking my HTML  with Amaya I detected that my navigation symbols (i. e. chapter forward) with `border="0"` are marked as deprecated. How to overcome this restriction? I don't want that my chapter forward symbol to be represented as link.

Example:
`<a href="...URL..."><img alt="chapter forward" src="../images/chforw.gif" border="0"></a>`

I've tried CSS `img {border:none }`, but this disable the link representation in all circumstances.

Comment: You set a class for your <img> tag, and then style that. This is basic CSS stuff. Any CSS book or tutorial should explain how to style classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image border in Strict HTML using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078761/image-border-in-strict-html-using-css)

Comment: @Code Gray: Indeed, thanks. (search in stackoverflow with `border="0"` does not hit the cited duplicate - at least in the first 50 out of thousands hits).

Comment: I cheat and use Google to search. :-) No worries, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gives a class to your element, for example

```
<a...><img class="vroum" alt="chapter forward" src="../images/chforw.gif"></a>
```

Then your CSS rule can be clean and specific to those elements :

```
.vroum {border:none }
```

Bonus (the whole point of CSS) : you'll be able to change the styling of all those elements without having to change the HTML everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

By styling your image tags accordingly:

```
<img alt="chapter forward" style="border: none;" src="../images/chforw.gif" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not like the border is deprecated, it used to be the way you are doing it but now, you have to understand that styling should be part of CSS and not image attribute like you are doing it above.
You can use the style attribute if you want to use the border as an inline CSS below:

```
<img alt="chapter forward" style="border: none;" src="../images/chforw.gif" border="0" />
```

Comment: Good point, in 2014 I was a novice concerning HTML respectively CSS and quoted the message given by amaya. This editor was very helpful to me at that times. BTW: What's the difference between your answer and Allmighty's one 6 years ago? Just to be curious...